# Updating MYSQL database with new record without erasing old one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How i can add information into database column without overwriting it on old one? I need both old and new information same column for example, old variable was A now i want it to be AB without deleting A.Any solutions with laravel framework?

Comment: Append the value? redesign your tables?

Comment: You need to insert another row in the database. Use the `created_at` column to discern which is newer.

Comment: for example i have user_name and user_friends_id and there was for example id 44 in user_friends id and now when new user with id 45 adds that user i need it to 44, 45  so old record will not be overwritten

Comment: You shouldn't save multiple ids to one field, i.e `user_friends_id`. It's not only ugly (you break `1NF`) but also uncomfortably to work with

Comment: Yes, @alexander.polomodov, plus: one wouldn't know how _wide_ to make that column. Consider Facebook, Justin B. and his trillions of friends. I'm pretty sure they don't store them comma-separated in a `varchar(25GB)` and parse that for hours to build a who-is-who or to remove one “friend”.

Comment: As Mark says you need to redesign your tables Google Relational Database Design.

Comment: so without putting it in one field how i can design friends field? i want to make to make one acount friend with many acounts